# Inequality between stopping times

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stopping-times

I have a problem with the following question:

Find an example of a stochastic process $X=(X_t)$ and a measurable subset $A$ of the state space such that the hitting times 
$\tau_0=\inf\{t\geq 0:X_t\in A\}$ and $\tau_1=\inf\{t>0:X_t\in A\}$ satisfy $$\tau_0<\tau_1.$$

So, my idea is to set $X_t=e^t$ and A=R, but i am not sure

Comment: What do you mean "Find the process X and A"?

Comment: Find the example of the process X and set A

Comment: I don't know what you mean by a process.  How is it represented?  Is it a function of $t$?  Real?  The title mentions stopping times.  How are they represented in the process, if they are?

Comment: Yes, this is function of t. For example, Xt = tWt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the set $A:=\{0\}$ and the deterministic process $X_t(\omega) := t$. Then

$$\tau_0 = \inf\{t \geq 0; X_t \in A\} = 0$$

but

$$\tau_1 = \inf\{t \geq 0; X_t \in A\} = \infty.$$